# How to check index in an Erlang list?

Tags: erlang

How I would like to make a new list which is originated from two different lists, so I make the below code, but it gives the unexpected result.

I am not sure why it happens. I would like to understand why this happens.

**What I expect.**

```
ListA = [1,2,3],

ListB = [a,b,c],

ListC = [{1,a}, {2,b}, {3,c}].
```

**What I get.**

ListC = [{1,a},{1,b},{1,c},{2,a},{2,b},{2,c},{3,a},{3,b},{3,c}]

```
ListA = [1,2,3],
ListB = [a,b,c],
LictC = [{A, B} || A<-ListA, B<-ListB]
```

Maybe..

```
ListA = [1,2,3],
ListB = [a,b,c],
LictC = [{A, B} || A<-ListA, B<-ListB, Condition]
```

If there is a function that to check the order of the array, it can be the condition. In detail, if the element of `ListA` has same index with the element of `ListB`, the condition function returns `true`.

Comment: lists:zip(ListA,ListB).

Answer (score 4):

> In Real
>
> ```
> ListC = [{1,a},{1,b},{1,c},{2,a},{2,b},{2,c},{3,a},{3,b},{3,c}]
>
> ListA = [1,2,3],
> ListB = [a,b,c],
> LictC = [{A, B} || A<-ListA, B<-ListB]
> ```
>
> I am not sure why it happens

Because that is the way list comprehensions are defined to work.  A list comprehension with two generators works exactly the same way as two nested for loops in other languages:

```
#python

listA = [1,2,3]
listB = ["a", "b", "c"]
results = []

for a in listA:
    for b in listB:
        results.append((a,b))

print(results)
```

output:

```
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), 
 (3, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

You take the first element of ListA, and you combine it with every element of ListB; then you take the second element of ListA, and you combine it with every element of ListB; etc.

> how can I fix this

"When you've got a hammer (list comprehensions) everything looks like a nail."  In this case, you've got the wrong tool for the job. Instead, you should use [lists:zip/2](https://erldocs.com/21.0/stdlib/lists.html?i=7&search=zip#zip/2) to get the result you want:

```
1> ListA = [1,2,3].
[1,2,3]

2> ListB = [a,b,c].
[a,b,c]

3> lists:zip(ListA, ListB).
[{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}]
```

Or, you can define your own recursive function to do what you want:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

combine([], []) -> [];
combine([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) ->
    [{H1,H2} | combine(T1, T2)].
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(a).                      
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

2> a:combine([1,2,3], [a,b,c]).
[{1,a},{2,b},{3,c}]

3>
```

> if the element of ListA has same index with the element of ListB

In erlang, the elements of a list do not have index positions.  Erlang lists are not the same as python lists or arrays in C/C++.  Rather erlang lists are implemented as linked lists, whose elements can be sequentially accessed but not randomly accessed.

Comment: Overall good answer, but I have to disagree with "In erlang, the elements of a list do not have index positions". Of course they do, and they can be accessed by them; just not in constant time, which isn't relevant in this context.

Comment: Thank you!  There is already the std function for this case. And the recursive function is also helpful.